# Does AnfengdeEpubReader reads data from local http server?

Tags: android, http, epub

1] I want a read access of the Anfengde EPub Reader. So i found one solution to read it using local http server in android. So can anyone tell me if it is possible.

2] Also I want to know if the sdk object can read the file using http:// Local server

Thank you!

Comment: What does `Anfengde` mean?!

Comment: Its an EPub Reader SDK. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wodehouse.ui.call&hl=en this app is a live example..